# Right to Left orientation difference between android smartphone to tablet using different language seetings

Tags: java, android

I developed an app and installed it both on my smartphone and tablet
Table is running andoird 5.0.2 where smartphone is running 4.4.2

On the tablet same app has right to left orientation(NavigationDrawer, List items etc..)

plus,

`new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy").format(dateandtime.getTime());`

gives difference output languages.

I assume it's related with the device language settings, but how can I align it for all devices no matter what language they use?

Comment: Set the orientation using `setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);` if you want it to be LTR irrespective of the language, and similarly `setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);` if you want to set RTL for all cases.

Comment: this should be call in each fragment ?

Comment: No, this parameter should be set to the View that you are adding.

Comment: thanks, this helped on view objects, what about dialog? the dialog window still changes from devices according to device basic language(rtl\ltr)

Comment: Good that it worked. I'll add it as an answer. Please accept it so that others know it's fixed. :) For a dialog, you could use `setView()` to set a view to the dialog, and set the layout of the view accordingly. I'll post a better answer if I come across one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the orientation using `setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);` if you want it to be LTR irrespective of the language, and similarly `setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);` if you want to set RTL for all cases.